# Does Starting A Tomcat Server On CentOS Crash PHP Sites Running On Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am running some `PHP` sites on a  `CentOS 6.6` server,

I have installed `Tomcat`.

If I start the `Tomcat server` will it crash my websites running in the `www dir`on `Apache`?

Or can `Tomcat` and `Apache` run at the same time?

Comment: You can't run on the same ports...

Comment: Right now when I go to mysite.com:8080 it shows nothing... So is that a safe assumption that I am not running anythinng on port 8080 and when I start tomcat none of my sites will  go off line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As long as they are running on different ports which they do by default you are all set.

Comment: Thank you I am excited to do this, I was terrified. I tried to sudo systemctl start tomcat but it says command not found.. any idea? I am on centos 6.6 and have tomcat installed to usr/share/tomcat all with yum